# PDF in paged mode (text split into individual pages)

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, pdf

When viewing epub files (e.g. with Calibre), in paged mode, the text is split up into individual pages, as in a paper book.

In paged mode the number of pages per screen can be also changed, e.g. to a two-page layout view.

I have not found any MacOs software that has the paged mode for pdf on screen as opposed to [splitting them to print](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12305/split-a-single-page-pdf-into-multiple-pages)

Does anybody knows a pdf viewer that implements the paged mode feature?

Comment: Preview can show two-pages side-by-side, in the manner of a book, or single page. As can most other PDF viewers. Is this not what you want? If you want to split one PDF page that happens to be a scan of two pages, then that's trickier.