# How to print one page PDF in a readable way

Tags: mac, pdf, printing

Good morning!

I have saved this internet page as pdf, and now I can't find a way to split it in more A4 format pages.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you use "Export As PDF" in Safari, then you get one enormous PDF.

If you use "Save As PDF" from the print menu, then you'll get the webpage split up onto your chosen page size.

[Split a single page PDF into multiple pages](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12305/split-a-single-page-pdf-into-multiple-pages?rq=1)

Most of the methods involve 'printing' the PDF again onto a page -- though you run the risk that any text falling across the margin will be chopped in half.